# How to calculate GPA from values from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```sql
create table student (
number      int identity(1,1) primary key,
s_id       int ,
s_full_name   varchar(50),
Academic_year   int,
sex        varchar(10),
block_num    int,
dorm_num    int,
depar_name    varchar(30),
c_name       varchar(30) foreign key references course(c_name),
grade      char,
GPA             float,
gradeWeight     float
);

create table studMark(
  c_name varchar(30), 
  ID int,
  marks_5 int,
  marks_10 int,
  marks_15 int,
  marks_20 int,
  marks_50 int
) 

update student set  s_id=p.ID,  grade=
CASE WHEN (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) > 84.5
    THEN 'A' 
    WHEN (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) < 84.5 AND (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) > 64.5
    THEN 'B'
    WHEN (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) < 64.5 AND (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) > 49.5
    THEN 'C'
    WHEN (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) < 49.5 AND (marks_5+marks_10+marks_15+marks_20+marks_50) > 29.5
    THEN 'D'
    ELSE 'F'
  end
  FROM studMark p, student s where s_id=p.ID and s.c_name=p.c_name

update student set gradeWeight=
 CASE WHEN grade='A'  
    THEN 4
   WHEN grade='B'  
    THEN 3.5
   WHEN grade='c'    
    THEN 3.0
   WHEN grade='D'  
    THEN  2.5
   WHEN grade='E'  
    THEN 2.0
  WHEN grade='F'  
    THEN  0
  end
  FROM student
```

The SQL below is to calculate GPA but it takes the average of the calculated value for all Id:

```
update student set GPA=
( select (sum(t.gradeWeight*c.c_cHr))/sum(c.c_cHr) as gpa from student t,Course c,studMark z where t.c_name=c.c_name and c.c_name= z.c_name and z.ID=t.s_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may join your existing query as shown below:

**Mysql Version**

```sql
UPDATE student s1
INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT 
        t.s_id, 
        (SUM(t.gradeWeight * c.c_cHr)) / SUM(c.c_cHr) AS gpa
    FROM
        student t, Course c, studMark z
    WHERE
        t.c_name = c.c_name AND 
        c.c_name = z.c_name AND 
        z.ID = t.s_id
    GROUP BY 
        t.s_id
) s_gpa ON s1.s_id = s_gpa.s_id 
                 
SET 
    s1.GPA = s_gpa.gpa
```

[View demo db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/atT9FbNW8xvZzcDGDEF6M7/0)

**SQL Server Version**

```sql
UPDATE student

        
SET 
    student.GPA = s_gpa.gpa
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        t.s_id, 
        (SUM(t.gradeWeight * c.c_cHr)) / SUM(c.c_cHr) AS gpa
    FROM
        student t, Course c, studMark z
    WHERE
        t.c_name = c.c_name AND 
        c.c_name = z.c_name AND 
        z.ID = t.s_id
    GROUP BY 
        t.s_id
) s_gpa 
WHERE student.s_id = s_gpa.s_id
```

[View demo db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=182df3f1b3a3060d6ef5d002c4b5315b)

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @ask123 I've updated the answer with a demo db fiddle. Let me know if this works for you. Although you tagged your question with mysql, i'm seeing `identity(1,1)` which is used in sql server. Is your database sql server? Let me know if the update with either query works for you.

Comment: Tnx man it works I appreciate it and it is sql my bad

Comment: @ask123 I'm glad that it worked for you. Please upvote this answer if you found it helpful. In addition, please mark this answer as the accepted answer so that other stackoverflow users with similar questions will be able to identify suitable answers to their questions.